# is there a way to filter words by length in a bag of words matrix in r?

Tags: r

I have created a matrix in R (called bag_of_words) I need to compute the top 100 most popular words (most occurrences), but filter tokens by length (min. size= 4 and max. size = 20) and indicate the total occurrences of the words.
I have created code to find the top 100 words without this filter which works, but cannot find a way of filtering words in matrix by length. Any help would be appreciated.

My attempt:

```
#view the top 100 most common words
term_f <- colSums(bag_of_words)
term_f <- sort(term_f, decreasing = T)
term_f[1:100]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I did not understand your question. But I think a vector might be easier to handle, especially if it is column of a `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
list_words <- data.table(x = as.numeric(bag_of_words))
```

If you only want words between 4 and 20 characters, use `nchar`:

```r
list_words <- list_words[nchar(x) %between% c(4,20)]
```

Count the number of occurrences for each words

```r
list_words <- list_words[,.(n = .N), by = "x"]
```

Get the top 100

```r
list_words <- list_words[arrange(desc(n))][1:100]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what NLP infrastructure you are using, but my recommendation is to use [**quanteda**](https://quanteda.io). If you don't have the package, just install it from CRAN with `install.packages("quanteda")`.

Please find below a way to easily solve your issue ahead of computing token frequencies.

```
library(quanteda)

text = c("some short tokens, but maybe just fine.",
         "thesearesomeverylongtokens.",
         "v e r y s hort tokens" )

mycorp = corpus( text )
mytok = tokens( mycorp )
my_selected_tok = tokens_keep( mytok, min_nchar = 4, max_nchar = 20 )

mydfm = dfm(my_selected_tok)
frequencies = textstat_frequency( mydfm )

> frequencies
  feature frequency rank docfreq group
1  tokens         2    1       2   all
2    some         1    2       1   all
3   short         1    2       1   all
4   maybe         1    2       1   all
5    just         1    2       1   all
6    fine         1    2       1   all
7    hort         1    2       1   all

> class(frequencies)
[1] "frequency"  "textstat"   "data.frame"
```